# Unity)second invokerepeating doesn't want to trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two invokeRepeating which needs to be triggered. I have two bools which decide which invokeRepeating needs to be triggered. 
The first invokeRepeating needs to be triggered when at least one of the two bools are set true,
and always second invokeRepeating needs to be triggered when two bools are set to false.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movingCharacter : MonoBehaviour {
public Rigidbody rb;
public float movingSpeed = 200;
public int maxSpeed = 3000;
public bool forwardBackMoving, sideMoving;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    forwardBackMoving = true;
    sideMoving = true;
    if ((forwardBackMoving == true || sideMoving == true)&&movingSpeed<maxSpeed)
    {
        InvokeRepeating("increaseSpeed", 5.0f, 5.0f);
    }
    else if(forwardBackMoving==false&&sideMoving==false)
    {
        CancelInvoke();
        InvokeRepeating("decreaseSpeed", 1.0f, 5.0f);
    }
}
public void keyUpEvent()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
    {
        forwardBackMoving = false;
    }else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
    {
        sideMoving = false;
    }
}

public void increaseSpeed() {
    movingSpeed = movingSpeed * 1.1f;
    Debug.Log("Increased");
}
public void decreaseSpeed()
{
    movingSpeed = movingSpeed * 0.9f;
    Debug.Log("Decreased");
}
// Update is called once per 

public void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * movingSpeed);
        forwardBackMoving = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.right * -movingSpeed);
        sideMoving = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * -movingSpeed);
         forwardBackMoving= true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.right * movingSpeed);
        sideMoving = true;
    }
    keyUpEvent();
    Debug.Log(Time.deltaTime);
   /* if ((forwardBackMoving == true || sideMoving == true) && movingSpeed < maxSpeed)
    {
        //while(Time.fixedDeltaTime)
    }
    else if (forwardBackMoving == false && sideMoving == false)
    {

        //InvokeRepeating("decreaseSpeed", 1.0f, 5.0f);
    }*/
}

 }
```

In this code, the second invokeRepeating never never triggers even the bools are changed to false..

Comment: Start is called once when instancing the component; any reasons why you called "CancelInvoke"?

Comment: @Slavi just forgot to delete it. Does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have an `if` - `else if` block there so only **one** of the two blocks can be executed at a time.

And as said `Start` is only called **once** for this Component so how should the other block any be reached?

What you want to do is rather `CancelInvoke` and `InvokeRepeating` **every time** one of the values changes. I would actually use [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for this:

```
public class movingCharacter : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [Header("References")]
    public Rigidbody rb;

    [Header("Settings")]
    public float movingSpeed = 200;
    public int maxSpeed = 3000;

    [Header("Debug")]
    [SerializeField] private bool _forwardBackMoving;
    [SerializeField] private bool _sideMoving;

    // Now make properties. When setting a new value run your checks
    public bool forwardBackMoving
    {
        get => _forwardBackMoving;
        set
        {
            // do nothing if the value hasn't changed
            if(_forwardBackMoving == value) return;

            // otherwise apply the new value and run the check
            _forwardBackMoving = value; 
            CheckMovement();
        }
    }

    // The same fot he other flag
    public bool sideMoving
    {
        get => _sideMoving;
        set
        {
            // do nothing if the value hasn't changed
            if(_sideMoving == value) return;

            // otherwise apply the new value and run the check
            _sideMoving = value;
            CheckMovement();
        }
    }

    private void CheckMovement()
    {
        if ((forwardBackMoving || sideMoving) && movingSpeed < maxSpeed)
        {
            CancelInvoke();
            InvokeRepeating(nameof(increaseSpeed), 5.0f, 5.0f);
        }
        else if(!forwardBackMoving && !sideMoving)
        {
            CancelInvoke();
            InvokeRepeating(nameof(decreaseSpeed), 1.0f, 5.0f);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        forwardBackMoving = true;
        sideMoving = true;
    }

    private void keyUpEvent()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
        {
            forwardBackMoving = false;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
        {
            sideMoving = false;
        }
    }

    private void increaseSpeed() 
    {
        movingSpeed = movingSpeed * 1.1f;
        Debug.Log("Increased");
    }

    private void decreaseSpeed()
    {
        movingSpeed = movingSpeed * 0.9f;
        Debug.Log("Decreased");
    }

    // You should get Input only in the Update method!
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.forward * movingSpeed);
            forwardBackMoving = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.right * -movingSpeed);
            sideMoving = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.forward * -movingSpeed);
             forwardBackMoving= true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.right * movingSpeed);
            sideMoving = true;
        }
        keyUpEvent();
        // Avoid Debug.Log on a per frame basis! It is quite expensive!
        Debug.Log(Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```